# type safe and nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to create 100% type safe compile time checking code?

Even criteria seems to reference column names with a string reference "Username", but if you put "Usernnameaa" it will fail at runtime right?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no. It looks like there is a project called [nhlambdaextensions](http://code.google.com/p/nhlambdaextensions/) which might be what you're wanting.

Answer (score 1):

Good news: You get it with Nhibernate3

See http://nhibernate.info/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx